# cant make my vaigation bar dropdown

Tags: css, razor

I have a navigation bar which is horizontal,i need to add some more links to one its Item but act like a dropdown list when I mouse hover,im new in css,html so please help me out with it,the following is current code:

```
   <ul>              
            <li 

                >@Html.ActionLink("ANALYSIS", "Powercurve", "PowerCurve", new { }, new { @class = "navItem" })

            </li>


        }
        //Admin


        if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(ParkViewerNG.Security.Role.POWERCURVE))
        {

            <li 
                  <text>class="nav-current"</text>
                }
                >@Html.ActionLink("ADMIN", "ListOfTurbines", "AdminTool", new { }, new { @class = "navItem" })

            </li>


        }

       // TestRanking

       //  Admin


           <li 

              >@Html.ActionLink("MANAGEMENT", "parkList", "Ranking", new { }, new { @class = "navItem" })


           </li>


  </ul>
```

Here is what I need to add to make it dropdown,i have tried but does not work,means it dosnt become dropdown,i don't know here to add it,

```
.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
  }
```

I add like following :

```
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

any help will be appreacited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could insert your dropdown content in the rest of your HTML in this way:

```
<ul>
  <li id="analysis">
    ANALYSIS
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>ADMIN</li>
  <li>MANAGEMENT</li>
</ul>
```

Your .dropdown-content CSS is correct, you just need to add a styling rule to state that the dropdown content must become visible on hovering over the menu item, for example:

```
ul li#analysis:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

I made [a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LLwuw8or/) to make this more clear.

What you could also do is save yourself some time and use a framework like Bootstrap. For your particular problem, have a look at Bootstrap's [Navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/). Unless you want to experiment with HTML and CSS to understand how these navigation bars are actually made under the hood.